# Turn on cypress uncaught:exception after turning it off

Tags: javascript, cypress, uncaught-exception, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm currently trying to use Cypress for the first time and turn off cypress uncaught:exception during a certain test but I would like to turn it on once the test finished.
How can I do that ? Thanks

PS: I disable it this way
`

```
cy.on('uncaught:exception', () => false);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As well as `cy.on()` you can use `cy.once()` which turns off after the first catch.

Or there is `cy.off()`.

Some examples from Cypress own code:

```js
cy.once('fail', (err) => {
  expect(err.message).to.match(/^A callback was provided ... /)
    .and.match(/ESOCKETTIMEDOUT|ETIMEDOUT/)
  done()
})
```

```js
cy.on('log:added', handleAddLog)
cy.on('fail', (err) => {
  cy.off('log:added', handleAddLog)
})
```

```js
const onNavChanged = (event) => {
  if (event === 'page navigation event (load)') {
    cy.off('navigation:changed', onNavChanged)
    cb()
  }
}

cy.on('navigation:changed', onNavChanged)
```

---

**Named handler**

Note the "named" function used for the handler - this is so that same listener is turned off (you can have multiple listeners, and turn them off individually).

So in your code

```js
const noError = () => false;
cy.on('uncaught:exception', noError);
...  // later
cy.off('uncaught:exception', noError);
```

---

**Type definitions**

```js
namespace CypressOnceTests {
  Cypress.once('uncaught:exception', (error, runnable) => {
    error // $ExpectType Error
    runnable // $ExpectType Runnable
  })

  cy.once('uncaught:exception', (error, runnable) => {
    error // $ExpectType Error
    runnable // $ExpectType Runnable
  })
}

namespace CypressOffTests {
  Cypress.off('uncaught:exception', (error, runnable) => {
    error // $ExpectType Error
    runnable // $ExpectType Runnable
  })

  cy.off('uncaught:exception', (error, runnable) => {
    error // $ExpectType Error
    runnable // $ExpectType Runnable
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `cy.on()` command to only the test you want to ignore uncaught exceptions for, it will only apply to that test.

See the example in this [Handling Errors recipe provided by Cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__errors/cypress/e2e/app-error.cy.js).

```js
  it('can be ignored', () => {
    /**
     * By using "cy.on()" we can ignore an exception in the current test only.
     * If you want to register exception handler for all tests using "Cypress.on()"
     * @see https://on.cypress.io/catalog-of-events
     * @param {Error} e The exception we caught
     * @param {Mocha.Runnable} runnable is the current test or hook during which the error is caught
     */
    cy.on('uncaught:exception', (e, runnable) => {
      console.log('error', e)
      console.log('runnable', runnable)

      // we can simply return false to avoid failing the test on uncaught error
      // return false
      // but a better strategy is to make sure the error is expected
      if (e.message.includes('Things went bad')) {
        // we expected this error, so let's ignore it
        // and let the test continue
        return false
      }
      // on any other error message the test fails
    })

    cy.visit('index.html')
    cy.get('button#error').click()
    // the error happens after 1000ms
    // we can use hard-coded wait, see the other test
    // to learn how to avoid an unnecessary wait
    cy.wait(1500)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag like this

```
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  cy.window().then((w) => {
    if (w.allowUncaughtExceptions) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Then in the test

```
  before(() => {
    cy.window().then(w => {
      w.allowUncaughtExceptions = true 
    })
  })

  after(() => {
    cy.window().then(w => {
      w.allowUncaughtExceptions = false 
    })
  })

// tests..
```